# php file_put_contents take file longer than script executes

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, time

If I don't use **sleep(3)**. Page refresh and take old file.  Or I use timer in js before reload it's help. But I think it's wrong way. I don't understand how return $ajax success after file_put_contents finished finally.

```
class OrderparamController extends FrontEndController 
{
      public function actionIndex($typeproduct = OrderService::TypePrintBannerCloth) {
        $forms = $this->requireFile('order-forms.php');
        $tplParams=array(
            'id_order' => $typeproduct,
            'forms' => $forms
        );
        $this->render('form',$tplParams);
    }

    /**
     * Require file
     */
    protected function requireFile($file_name){
        $configFile = YiiBase::getPathOfAlias('application.cache').'/'.$file_name;
        $handle = fopen($configFile, "r");
        fclose($handle);
        require $configFile;
        return $forms; 
    }
/*
     * Удалить параметр
     */
    public function actionDeleteparamoption() {
        $configFile='order-forms.php';
        $forms=$this->requireFile($configFile);
        $keyfield = $_POST['keyfield'];
        $id_order = (int)$_POST['id_order'];
        $numoption = $_POST['numoption'];
        unset($forms[$id_order]['fields'][$keyfield]['options'][$numoption]);
        if ($this->writeFile($forms,$configFile)) {
            $answer=array(
                'ok' => true,
            );
        } else {
            $answer=array(
                'ok' => false,
            );
        }
        **sleep(3);**
        echo json_encode($answer);
    }
}
```

I use js for sending ajax

```
 $('.js-btn-delete').on('click',function(){
            var request ={
                keyfield : $(this).data('keyfield'),
                id_order : Var.id_order,
                label : $(this).data('label'),
                numoption : $(this).data('option'),
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: '/orderparam/deleteparamoption',
                type: 'POST',
                data: request,
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                success: deleteOrderParamResult
            })
        });
        function deleteOrderParamResult(data){
            if (data.ok) {
                var num=intVal($('.param-option').index($('.param-option:visible')));
                document.cookie = "viewOption="+num;
                location.reload();
            } else {
                alert('ошибка');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try putting `echo json_encode($answer);` inside the `if ($this->writeFile){echo here} else{echo here}` construction. Or use `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()`.

Comment: I tried  putting echo json_encode($answer); inside the if. Still the same. What do you mean about ob_start() and ob_end_flush() ?

Comment: I meant it could have been the script is echoing before the file has finished writing. I'm not quite understanding what you are doing. Are you writing to the file on display and then reload it?In that case you might have a problem with caching. Try to reload it with `filename.php?somerandom_number` to force a reload of the page